# "Cannot import name x" when using namedtuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

So, I defined a couple of namedtuples in a separate file "types.py":

```
import collections

TestWindow  = collections.namedtuple('TestWindow', 'HWND rect x y w h refPoint')
Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
```

and would like to import these types in another file:

```
from types import TestWindow, Point

def main():
    pass
```

And as soon as I add the first import line, I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from types import TestWindow, Point
ImportError: cannot import name 'TestWindow'
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error. I created the two files exactly as you present them here, ran `python main.py` and it worked fine.

Comment: What are you not telling us?

Comment: I just copied my code into two new files and ran it with `python main.py` and am still getting the mentioned error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [module in stdlib named `types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html), it gets imported instead.

Either rename your module, or switch to absolute imports.

Comment: This is probably the right answer, but why did it work when I was doing it?

Comment: Indeed! Thank you! Really strange, in another project on the same computer with exactly the same python environment (python 3.4 on windows), I didn't have this problem even though the file was called types.py aswell.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Did you use Python 3?

Comment: @9000. Yes, exclusively